# How to hide particle source in proxy

Tags: particles, linked-data

I have a rig consisting of 3 objects and a skeleton. One of the objects is a particle emitter, using a ball object to render the particles. I put the ball in a different layer so I could render the balls emitted as particles, but not the original one. The 3 objects, skeleton and ball object were put into a group and linked into another file, and I created a proxy for the skeleton to animate it. Things are good, but I can't find a way to hide that original ball in the linked file. There is no way to put it in a different layer as it's part of the group. The ball particles render fine, but so does the original ball. Is there a different technique that will accomplish this?

[image: Extra ball]

Comment: If you can select the ball separately, then you can also move it to another layer, isn't that the case? I don't think there is some restriction prohibiting moving parts of a group to other layer.

Comment: You would think, but even though it highlights like that, I can't move it to another layer :(. I can't move it or do anything to it separately as far as I can tell.  In general you can't do anything to items of a group that you link into another file. You can only do things to the group itself, which affects all the objects in it.

Comment: Make the ball local then, and move it to another layer.

Answer (score 1):

What Mzidare said was right. I went back to the project today, and tried again. Yes, you can select the ball separately and move it to another layer just like you would if the group was not linked. I tried it with the ball included in the group I linked and with it not in the group and I had the same result. I was pretty sure that I had tried that before, but I guess I must have done something wrong.  Mzidare, if you want you can re-post your comment as an answer and I'll up-vote it.